Install xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 5.0.0 Package
We are migrating from v8.2 to v10.0.1:

Installed new vanilla Sitecore 10.0.1 (all 10.x DLLs).
Pointed master, web, core SC 8.2 databases to 10.0.1. Sitecore instance is up and running. We see all the 8.2 items.
Migrated MongoDB to SQL. While installing "Install xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 5.0.0 Package", see the below error:

Exception: System.TypeLoadException
Message: Could not load type 'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.Conditions.ChannelMapCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer'.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)

2464 12:13:07 ERROR [Path Analyzer] Error during aggregation.
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException
Message: No known predicate type could be determined from 'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.Conditions.ChannelMapCondition,Sitecore.PathAnalyzer' specified in the definition item (Id = '51da8f3e-8ea5-4129-8ea2-a275be3a6b2d', db = 'master') : Could not load type 'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.Conditions.ChannelMapCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer'.
Source: Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.xMgmt
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.LookupType(Guid descriptorId)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.AndXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.TreeConverter.TreeConverter`2.Convert(TFromNode treeRoot)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.RuleXmlConverter.CreateRule(XElement ruleElement)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildXmlRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesValidator.ValidateRule(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters parameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.IsApplicable(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters conditionParameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.Build(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.AggregationContextCollector.Collect(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.TreeAggregator.Aggregate(ItemBatch`1 batch)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()


It looks like the old Sitecore DLLs have not been replaced by a new set of DLLs.

The fundamental challenge here is that the maps in the Path Analyzer are based on rule sets which have been significantly redesigned in Sitecore version 9.0 and from now on are stored in a different format.
Therefore, while upgrading from any Sitecore version 8.x you have to upgrade the Path Analyzer by reconfiguring and then redeploying your maps. See section "8.3.9 Upgrading from Sitecore XP 8.1 – 8.2.7" in the Upgrade Guide.
How to redeploy the Path Analyzer maps

Back up your Reporting database just in case before proceeding further.

In SQL Server Management Studio, in the Reporting database, run the following command to remove all the data from the TreeDefinitions table:
Delete from TreeDefinitions

In Sitecore, open the Path Analyzer admin page /sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx

In the Maps Manager section, click Deploy all maps that are not deployed


